# Visual Studio/Machine refusing external connections

Tags: networking, windows-10, visual-studio, data-transfer, external-data

Since going over to Windows 10, I have had numerous issues which I have mostly resolved.

One problem that I cannot get resolved is that my Visual Studio does not manage to get external link data. I was developing a data input program which consumes 3rd party sources (mostly via REST API sources). All worked fine and is deployed from my Windows 8 machine.

Now I have replaced that machine with a new one and had to use Windows 10. 
I get the following error:

> the target machine actively refused it.
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I tried to be methodical and went through the firewall rules, which didn't work.
So I turned it off completely. 
Still the error was the same.

Next I have gone through the same with anti-virus. 
Still get the same error.

So I uninstalled anti-virus (to make sure). 
With both firewall off and the anti-virus uninstalled, I still get this error.

To try to get it down to raw basics, I am using a totally simple basic (C++) project that gets the same error as a result of calling 3rd party source;
you can see it below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    var time =
        Disposable
        .Using(
            () => new System.Net.WebClient(),
            client => 
                   XDocument.Parse(client.DownloadString("http://time.gov/actualitime.cgi")))
        .Root
        .Attribute("time")
        .Value;
    var ms = Convert.ToInt64(time) / 1000;
    var currentTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(ms).ToLocalTime();

    //currentTime.Dump;
}
```

The error is thrown on the line that calls the 3rd party data:

```
                   XDocument.Parse(....
```

I have checked the same code on other machines on our network to exclude the network firewall from the list of potential problems – it happily works on all other machines on the same network.

So I am at a loss and grateful for any guidance or help you can suggest.

Comment: It’s *super* unlikely this is in any way related to Windows 10 or even your software. You should first make sure the network is set up correctly. Because the error message indicates it isn’t.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, was hoping for some inspiration from others. The thing is about blaming the network is that the server is on the exact same network and it works fine. It does seem limited to debug mode in Visual Studio (at least to me who is definitely not feel like an expert)